# following error :TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to find the outlier value at specific indices and passing the following code, what should I do?

```py
array2=([26, 23, 26, 24, 15, 213, 19, 18, 17, 170, 20, 21, 16, 21, 19, 23, 21, 17, 19, 17, 28, 20, 27, 122, 23])
z_score_values=np.abs(zscore(array2))
z_score_values

outliers_index= np.where(z_score_values >=2)[0]
outliers_list = array2[outliers_index]
outliers_index
```

It results into following error:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: You can convert `array2` to `np.array` and use same approach. `np.array(array2)[outliers_index]`

Comment: It was my mistake, I did not convert array2 into array. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

`outliers_list = array2[outliers_index]` is in this line because you provide a whole list in an index.

```
outliers_list = array2[outliers_index[any number present in outlier_index]]
```

just like

```
outliers_list = array2[outliers_index[0]]
```

Comment: but when i run this code it gives me error to this line so i think this will be the problem same as title

Comment: Your is correct. `array2` is an normal python `list`